# How to transition to gradle/maven one project at a time by depending on projects that don't declare their dependencies

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependency-management

My situation is this:
I am sick of using ant in my workplace for obvious reasons (unmaintainable build scripts, annoying to introduce new dependencies) and want to use gradle (or maven). I have a couple projects that I manage, and I am free to do what I want with them. My projects depend on a small number of other company projects, and those project owners are not going to switch to gradle in the near future and this is not a negotiable point. I rarely need to change the versions of the projects that I depend on, so I figure that I can configure a company repository with Nexus or something similar and just upload those jars there.

The problem that I am not sure how to solve though is this: these ant projects don't declare their dependencies, they just depend on things being in the "libs/" folder. So by sucking in just the final jar, I wouldn't have all the required dependencies. I could bundle all the dependencies into the jar, but then the dependency information is lost to gradle and I feel like this could lead to really hard to debug dependency resolution problems.

One option that I see is to make a complete list of things that this project depends on, and stick all of those dependencies into my projects. The other option that I can see is to basically have some sort of fake gradle project that does absolutely nothing but claims that it depends on the jar from the other project and all of its dependencies, so by importing this fake project, I can "pretend" that this other project is gradle managed.

Are either of these sane things to do? Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When publishing a legacy project to Nexus, author and publish a pom.xml along with it that describes the project's dependencies. Gradle's or Maven's transitive dependency resolution will then take care of the rest.